# Les expressions métaphoriques se référant aux animaux

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, zoologie

> Minute, **papillon** !

Le nom « papillon » se réfère avec humour à une personne qui fait preuve d'inattention lors d'une conversation, ayant du mal à se concentrer, ou bien qui ne fait que papillonner d'un sujet à l'autre. C’est effectivement comme un papillon voletant de fleur en fleur, dans n'importe quelle direction comme bon lui semble.

> Au risque de me répéter comme un **perroquet**, ...

Quelqu’un comme un « perroquet », ça parle de soi-même... mais il s’agit de répéter la même chose en boucle, ne semblant pas s'en lasser, et ce, éventuellement jusqu’à ce que son interlocuteur commence à en avoir soupé.

J‘aimerais trouver d'autres expressions semblables, comme « un œil de **lynx** », qui se réfèrent métaphoriquement aux traits de caractère divers et variés de personnes, en les comparant aux traits caractéristiques d'animaux, d'oiseaux, d'insectes et de poissons particuliers – ainsi que des termes affectueux comme « mon **lapin** ».

Comment: note that there are different hypotheses about the origin of "minute, Papillon" and it seems that Papillon refers to a waiter in a famous Parisian Café http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/minute-papillon.phphttp://www.expressio.fr/expressions/minute-papillon.php

Comment: Animaux vivants seulement ou peuvent-ils être morts ?

Comment: @Laure Oui, tant qu'elles sont employées dans la langue de tous les jours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Community wiki**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/176183)

**Autruche**
  - Faire l’~ <sub>(refuser de constater les faits, d’admettre la réalité)</sub>
  - Avoir un estomac d’~ <sub>(manger n'importe quoi)</sub>
**Bouc**
  - Un ~ émissaire <sub>(personne qui prend toute la faute d’une situation, y compris celle des autres)</sub>
**Bourdon**
  - Avoir le ~ <sub>(souffrir de mélancolie)</sub>
**Cafard**
  - Avoir le ~ <sub>(souffrir de mélancolie)</sub>
**Chien**
  - Avoir du ~ <sub>(se démarquer du lot)</sub>
**Cochon**
  - Caractère de ~ <sub>(très mauvais caractère)</sub>
**Crocodile**
  - Larmes de ~ <sub>(Larmes hypocrites par lesquelles on cherche à émouvoir quelqu’un pour le tromper)</sub>
**Éléphant**
  - Mémoire d’~ <sub>(mémoire remarquable)</sub>
**Escargot**
  - Course d'~
<sub>(Tout le monde prend son temps pour éviter une tâche jugée ingrate)</sub>
**Grenouille**
  - ~ de bénitier <sub>(<sup>*Péjoratif*</sup> Personne qui affiche une piété excessive)</sub>
  - Grenouiller <sub>(magouiller, ne pas jouer franc-jeu, entre autres en politique)</sub>
  - Un homme-~ <sub>(personne en train de faire de la plongée sous-marine)</sub>
**Grue**
  - Faire le pied de ~ <sub>(attendre longtemps debout sans bouger ou en ne bougeant que très peu)</sub>
**Guêpe**
  - Pas folle, la ~ ! <sub>(qqn qu’on ne trompe pas facilement)</sub>
  - Taille de ~ <sub>(très mince)</sub>
**Huitre**
  - Avoir le charisme d’une ~ <sub>(très peu de charisme)</sub>
**Linotte**
  - Tête de ~ <sub>(étoudi, incapable de concentration ou d’attention)</sub>
**Lion**
  - Manger du ~ <sub>(avoir beaucoup d’énergie)</sub>
  - Un ~ <sub>*(homme célèbre, homme en vue dans la société,* puis, par glissement, *jeune homme élégant et oisif)*</sub>
  - Une lionne <sub>*(femme qui remporte de nombreux succès mondains,* puis *femme élégante et aux mœurs libres)*</sub>
**Loup**
  - Avoir une faim de ~ <sub>*(avoir très faim)*</sub>
**Moineau / Oiseau**
  - Appétit de moineau / d’oiseau <sub>(très peu d’appétit)</sub>
  - Cervelle de moineau / d’oiseau  <sub>(étoudi, à la compréhension ou à la mémoire défaillante)</sub>
**Mouton**
  - des moutons, une bande de moutons <sub>(<sup>Péjoratif</sup> Gens qui suivent la foule, qui adhèrent à une opinion sans se poser de questions)</sub>
  - ~ enragé <sub>(se dit d’une personne habituellement douce qui entre dans une grande colère)</sub>
  - ~ noir <sub>(se dit d’une personne qui détonne dans un groupe, particulièrement si elle est peu appréciée)</sub>
**Papillon**
  - Nage style papillon <sub>(ou *la nage papillon*, *le style papillon*, voire simplement *le papillon*)</sub>
  - Papillonner ~ <sub>(passer d’un sujet à l’autre, d’un partenaire amoureux à l’autre, ... d’une manière nonchalante, sans prévenir ou prendre le temps de mesurer les conséquences)</sub>
**Poisson rouge**
  - Mémoire de ~ <sub>(très mauvaise mémoire)</sub>
**Raie**
  - Face de ~ <sub>(?)</sub>
**Rat**
  - Face de ~ <sub>(insulte lié à la physionomie (déplaisante) du rat)</sub>
  - Un ~ <sub>(un avare)</sub>
  - ~ de bibliothèque <sub>(qui passe beaucoup de temps dans les livres)</sub>
  - ~ visqueux <sub>(?)</sub>
**Requin**
  - ~ de la finance / des affaires <sub>(personne très avisée et impitoyable en affaires)</sub>
**Thon**
  - Face de ~ <sub>(?)</sub>
**Vache**
  - Manger de la ~ enragée <sub>(vivre dans le dénuement)</sub>
  - ~ à lait <sub>(Qui est la source principale de l’enrichissement de qqn. S’applique autant aux humains qu’aux animaux, aux choses ou aux concepts)</sub>
**Vipère**
  - Langue de ~ <sub>(se dit de qqn de médisant)</sub>
  - ~ lubrique

__

### Comparaisons

<sub>*La comparaison est souvent exprimée, mais pas obligatoirement*</sub>

#### Par animal

**Agneau**  *Doux comme un ~*
**Âne**  *Bête comme un ~*
**Arapède** *Collant comme une ~* (Provence, personne trop collante)
**Belette**  *Curieux comme une ~*
**Bœuf**  *Fort comme un ~*
**Canard**  *Comme de l’eau sur le dos d’un ~*, *Marcher / se dandiner comme un ~*
**Carpe**  *Muet comme une ~*
**Chameau**  *Sobre comme un ~*
**Chat**  *Curieux comme un ~*, *Retomber comme un ~ sur ses pattes*
**Chien**  *Comme un ~ dans un jeu de quilles*, *Malade comme un ~*
**Cochon**  *Gras comme un ~*
**Coq**  *Fier comme un ~*, *Rouge comme un ~*
**Écrevisse**  *Rouge comme une ~*
**Escargot**  *Lent comme un ~*
**Hareng**  *Coincés / serrés comme des ~ (en caque)*, *Sec comme un ~*
**Homard**  *Rouge comme un ~*
**Lapin**  *Courir comme un ~*, *Chaud comme un ~*
**Limace**  *Lent comme une ~*
**Loir**  *Dormir comme un ~*
**Marmotte**  *Dormir comme une ~*
**Mule**  *Têtu comme une ~*
**Oie**  *Bête comme une ~*
**Ours**  *Fort comme un ~*, *<sup>(Québec)</sup> Il fait noir comme dans le cul d’un ~*
**Paon**  *Fier comme un ~*
**Pie**  *Bavard comme une ~*, *Voleur comme une ~*
**Pinson**  *Gai comme un ~*
**Poisson**  *Comme un ~ dans l’eau*
**Pou**  *Fier comme un ~*, *Laid comme un ~*, *Vexé comme un ~*
**Puce**  *Excité comme une ~*
**Rat**  *Être fait / pris comme un ~* <sub>*(pris au piège sans issue possible)*</sub>
**Renard**  *Rusé comme un ~*
**Ruminant quelconque** *Bête à manger du foin*
**Sardines**  *Coincés / serrés comme des ~*
**Serin**  *Bête comme un ~*, *Niais comme un ~*
**Singe**  *Malin comme un ~*
**Taupe**  *Myope comme une ~*
**Taureau**  *Fort comme un ~*
**Veau**  *Pleurer comme un ~*
**Ver**  *Nu comme un ~*

#### Par terme associé

**Bavard**  *~ comme une pie*
**Bête**  *~ comme un âne, une oie, un serin* • *~ à manger du foin*
**Coincés**  *~ comme des harengs (en caque), des sardines*
**Copains** *~ comme cochons*
**Courir**  *~ comme un lapin*
**Curieux**  *~ comme une belette, un chat*
**Se dandiner**  *~ comme un canard*
**Dormir**  *~ comme un loir, une marmotte*
**Doux**  *~ comme un agneau*
**Eau**  *Comme de l’~ sur le dos d’un canard* • *Comme un poisson dans l’~*
**Excité**  *~ comme une puce*
**Fier**  *~ comme un coq, un paon, un pou*
**Fort**  *~ comme un bœuf, un ours, un taureau*
**Gai**  *~ comme un pinson*
**Gras**  *~ comme un cochon*
**Jeu de quilles**  *Comme un chien dans un ~*
**Laid**  *~ comme un pou*
**Lent**  *~ comme un escargot, une limace*
**Malade**  *~ comme un chien*
**Malin**  *~ comme un singe*
**Marcher**  *~ comme un canard*
**Muet**  *~ comme une carpe*
**Myope**  *~ comme une taupe*
**Niais**  *~ comme un serin*
**Noir**  *<sup>(Québec)</sup> Il fait ~ comme dans le cul d’un ours*
**Nu**  *~ comme un ver*
**Pleurer**  *~ comme un veau*
**Retomber**  *~ comme un chat sur ses pattes*
**Rouge**  *~ comme un coq, une écrevisse, un homard*
**Rusé**  *~ comme un renard*
**Sec**  *~ comme un hareng*
**Serrés**  *~ comme des harengs (en caque), des sardines*
**Têtu**  *~ comme une mule*
**Vexé**  *~ comme un pou*
**Voleur** *~ comme une pie*

__

#### Référence à des animaux cuits pour être consommés

Se sentir comme un coq en pâte.
Des yeux de merlans frits.

__

#### Termes affectueux

Ma biche / (ma) bichette.
Ma cocotte.
Mon lapin.
Ma poulette / Ma poule.
Mon poussin.
Ma puce.
Mon petit canard en sucre.

#### Termes peu affectueux

Ma morue.
Mon maquereau.
Mon thon.
Mon cochon (de mari).

__

#### Météorologie

Entre chien et loup
Un temps de chien
Un vent à décorner / écorner les vaches / bœufs
Un froid de canard

__

#### Couleurs

*Aile de corbeau*
*Caca d’oie* <sub>(attesté jadis sous les noms *merde d’oyson*, puis *merde d’oie*)</sub>
*Chamois*
*Jaune canari*
*Jaune serin*
*Rouge cardinal*
*Sang de bœuf*
*Saumon*
*Souris*
*Taupe*
*Vert perroquet*

Comment: Community wiki.. à chacun de compléter / modifier.

Comment: Un temps de chien ? J'avais compris que la question portait sur  des « traits de caractère divers et variés de personnes »?